# How to find duplicate in one to one mappings in oracle using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have table as:

```
 ID           PAYOR_NAME 
----------   ------------

   4             AETNAU             
   4              AETNA                                           
   2              UMR                
   3            CIGNA                   
   1           METLIFE
```

Id needs to be one to one mapping with payor_name.But Id 4 is associated with multiple payor_name ,so it is considered as duplicate. So,I tried to find the duplicate by using:

```
select id, count(*) duplic_data
from (
    select distinct id, payor_name
    from offc.payor_collec
    order by id) t1
group by id;
```

It is giving me the duplicate Id,But i am wondering is there any also way where we can find duplicates in one to one mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of finding it:

- using `exists`
- using `group by` and `having`
- using `analytical` function, if you want all column data for that duplicate values (same as `exists`)

-

```
select id, payor_name, cnt as count_
from (
    select id, payor_name, 
           count(1) over (partition by id) as cnt
    from offc.payor_collec) t1
Where cnt > 1;
```

It will give you following result:

```
 ID           PAYOR_NAME   COUNT_
----------   ------------  -------

   4             AETNAU    2         
   4              AETNA    2
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

How about simply using `exists`:

```
select pc.id, pc.payor_name, count(*)
from offc.payor_collec pc
where exists (select 1
              from offc.payor_collec pc2
              where pc2.id = pc.id and pc2.payor_name <> pc.payor_name
             )
group by pc.id, pc.payor_name
order by pc.id, count(*) desc;
```

This also orders by the most frequent value, which might be helpful in figuring out the best name.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way:

```
select ID, count(*)
from offc.payor_collec
group by ID
having count(distinct PAYOR_NAME) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be using a subquery containing `having` clause with `having count(ID)>1`

```
select * 
  from payor_collec 
 where ID in
( select ID
    from payor_collec t
   group by ID
  having count(ID)>1 )
```